# AIO support on Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, aio

Does anyone know where I can get up to date information about the state on Kernel support for aio on the latest Linux Kernel?. Google searches bring up web pages that may be hopelessly out of date.

Edit:

More specifically, I am interested in non-file related descriptors like pipes and sockets. Stuff on the web indicate that there is no support, is this still the case?

Edit2:
What I am looking for is something similar to Windows OVERLAPPED IO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AIO support has been included in the linux kernel proper.  That's why [the first hit on Google](http://lse.sourceforge.net/io/aio.html) only offers patches to the 2.4 Linux kernel.  In 2.6 and 3.0 it's already in there.

If you checkout the Linux kernel source code, it's at fs/aio.c

There's [some documentation in the GNU libc manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Asynchronous-I_002fO.html), but be advised that aio is not possible for all types of Linux file descriptors.  Most of [the general "how to" documentation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-async/index.html) is dated around 2006, which is appropriate since that's when AIO in Linux was making the headlines.

Note that the POSIX.1b and Unix98 standards haven't changed, so can you be a bit specific as to the nature of the "out-of-date"ness of the examples?

Comment: @doron, that is the first hit on Google I mentioned above.  The POSIX.1b standard was laid out in 1997, the Unix98 spec was laid out in 1998.  Documentation form the mid 2000's isn't a make-or-break point, just ignore the details that apply to kernels prior to 2.6 (like patching instructions).

Comment: and what about socket support?

Comment: AIO operates on file descriptors, sockets are tracked via file descriptors too.

Comment: Linux AIO have severe limitations, including being unable to use the buffer cache. It seems like a quick implementation by some big company for their specific needs.

Comment: lvella- So if I read this correctly, aio is a second-class citizen on Linux and probably should be avoided.

Comment: @Edwin - I am referring to my first link above where is states that sockets are not properly supported by aio.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need POSIX AIO (i.e. man aio) to use sockets and pipes asynchronously. According to `man 3 aio` it is not even possible. You should use **non-blocking file descriptors** instead, together with an **event notification interface**, such as `select()`, `poll()`, or `epoll`. `epoll` is Linux specific, but scales much better than the former two.

To use file descriptors in non-blocking mode you have to set the `O_NONBLOCK` flag on every file descriptor:

```
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK)
```

After a file descriptor is in non-blocking mode, I/O operations like `read()` and `write()` will never block, but will return `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` if the operation cannot be completed immediately. Some more specific operations, like `connect()`, have to be used in a different way in non-blocking mode; see relevant man pages.

To be able to use non-blocking file descritors correctly, your application needs to be [event driven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_driven_programming). Basically, in `main()`, you need to first initialize stuff, then enter the *event loop*. The event loop repetedly waits for events (using an event notification interface, e.g. `epoll_wait()`), then checks which events happened, and responds to them.

Now when you do say a `read()`, and it fails with `EWOULDBLOCK`, you add it to the list of file descriptors watched for readability; when the event provider indicates readability, you try again.

Similarly, if you try to `write()` and it fails with `EWOULDBLOCK`, you might want to buffer the data and try again when writability is indicated.

Comment: I know this. The problem however means that more system calls are being made than are 100% necessary.

Comment: Yes, it's not exactly optimal, but are you actually seeing performance issues? I believe the overhead compared to a pure AIO interface is insignificant as long your program does any processing of the data it works with.

Comment: By the time you see performance issues, the architecture is too deeply entrenched to fix, you might as well design efficiently from the ground up.

Comment: Really? Then I suggest that you make an AIO-style abstraction of I/O, and implement it on top of whatever the OS provides (try non-blocking first). If it turns out that non-blocking sockets are too slow, you can reimplement that abstraction on top of a true AIO kernel interface (you might have to implement/improve such a kernel interface yourself). That's what I did in my BadVPN open source project; I use blocking sockets on Linux, but IOCP (true AIO) in Windows. http://code.google.com/p/badvpn/source/browse/trunk/system/BConnection.h

Comment: I think you've being brainwashed by Microsoft, doron. Just because overlapped I/O is the fastest way to do I/O on Windows doesn't mean it's the best way to do I/O everywhere. POSIX semantics are different from Windows semantics. Witness how imperfect all the POSIX wrappers for Windows are, and vice versa. If it were possible to treat all platforms the same, such wrappers would be thin and fast.

Comment: The actual problem is that Windows Overlapped IO can achieve memory zero copy, but epoll + nonblock io does not. The POSIX AIO API can achieve this in principle, but on Linux there is only an inefficient simulation layer.

Comment: So if the socket is ready, NIO or not, this means the thread will be busy doing actual read/write?

Answer (score 3):

There are **two** kinds of AIO under Linux.

One is kernel-AIO. It is ugly and sometimes does not behave in accordance with the documentation (for example, it will run synchronously under certain conditions without you being able to do something about it, and it will not properly cancel in-flight requests under certain conditions, etc, etc). It does **not** work on pipes.
These are the `io_` kind of functions. Note that you must link with `-laio`, which you must separately install on some systems (e.g. Debian/Ubuntu).

The second is is a pure userland implementation (glibc) which spawns threads on demand to handle requests. It is well-documented, works reasonably well, and according to the documentation, and it works with pretty much anything that is a file descriptor **including pipes**.
These are the `aio_`kind of functions. I would definitively recommend to use these, even if they are an "uncool userland implementation" -- they work nicely.

Both work with eventfd as a notification mechanism in the mean time, btw, though the kernel version was still undocumented last time I looked (but the funciton is in the headers).

Or, as Ambroz Bizjak pointed out, skip AIO at all, for what you describe it's not strictly necessary.

**EDIT:**
On a different note, since you used the words "pipes" and "sockets", are you aware of [vmsplice](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/vmsplice.2.html) and [splice](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/splice.2.html)? Those are the probably most efficient functions to send data to/from sockets/pipes. Unluckily, it's another one of those ambiguously documented, hard to understand hacks with obscure pitfalls. Proceed at your own risk, you have been warned.

`splice` lets you transfer data from a socket (or *any* file descriptor) to a pipe, or the other way around. `vmsplice` lets you transfer data between application space and a pipe.
Ironically, `vmsplice` is ideally supposed to do the exact same thing (remap pages, a.k.a. "play with VM") that one particular person took as argument to claim that all BSD developers are idiots, back in 2006.

So much for the good news, the bad news is that there is a "secret limit" to how much data you can move. As far as I remember it's 64kB (but configurable somewhere in /proc). If you have more data than that, you must therefore work in several chunks, presumably with several pipe buffers, filling one while the other is read, and reusing old pipe buffers after they are done.
And this is where it gets complicated. If you browse through the discussions Kernel Trap, you find that even the Grand Master is not 100% sure about when it's safe to overwrite an old buffer when juggling with several buffers.

Also, for `vmsplice` to *really* work (i.e. remapping pages instead of copying), you need to use the "GIFT" flag, and at least to me it's not clear from the docs what becomes of that memory then. Following the docs to the letter, you would need to leak memory, since you are never allowed to touch it again. Of course that can't be it. Maybe I'm just stupid.

I eventually gave up on this, and just settled for using `epoll` for readiness and non-blocking sockets with plain normal `write`. That combination is maybe not the utmost performer, but it is well-documented *and works as documented*.

Comment: I am not interested in userside aio since it is unlikely to be system-call efficient and spawning more threads does get resource hungry.

Comment: Yes, that is probably everybody's first thought, it's what I said too initially. Surprisingly, it works _much_ better and more reliably (from what I can tell) than the kernel implementation. Kernel AIO is more or less a "Yo, so you want DMA?" hack. If you exceed some unknown threshold, bad luck. If you want something that is not a block device with DMA, bad luck. If you want to use the buffer cache, bad luck. If "...", bad luck. The GNU userland implementation, on the other hand, just does AIO in the sense of _asynchronous IO_, which is just what one normally expects to happen. It just works.