# O_DIRECT vs. AIO_RAW

Tags: c++, file, asynchronous, posix, device

When using POSIX asynchronous I/O, are there any differences between using `O_DIRECT` and `AIO_RAW`? Or should I/can I use both? We are working on a NoSQL database server and are looking at ways of making asynchronuous I/O more efficient on POSIX systems.

[open(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open):

> **O_DIRECT** Try to minimize cache effects of the I/O to and from this file. In general this will degrade performance, but it is useful in
>   special situations, such as when applications do their own caching.
>   File I/O is done directly to/from user space buffers.

[aiocb(5)](http://uw714doc.sco.com/en/man/html.5/aiocb.5.html):

> You may set the **AIO_RAW** flag bit in the aio_flags structure member
>   when the asynchronous I/O is being done to a raw device partition.
>   When the **AIO_RAW** flag bit is set, asynchronous I/O might possibly be
>   more efficient.

Comment: Doesn't aio_write on Linux spawn a thread each time?  This always seemed to me like a losing proposition--it may be better not to use AIO at all (at least on Linux until it's better).

Comment: @JohnZwinck There is an interesting discussion on the subject here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87892/what-is-the-status-of-posix-asynchronous-i-o-aio , it says `"Direct, unbuffered I/O is only really useful for transactional databases, and those tend to write their own threads or processes to manage their disk I/O."` - which is our scenario as we are working on a transactional NoSQL database server product. We manage our own user thread pool.

Comment: I'm not saying don't try to do direct, unbuffered I/O.  I'm saying consider not using AIO.  And that's pretty much what the page you linked says too: avoid AIO.  Use O_DIRECT if you want, but never AIO_RAW, because never AIO.   :)

Comment: @JohnZwinck I think that as long as we are managing our own user thread pool we should be ok; the nice thing with POSIX AIO is that it works on every file system (ext2, ext3, jfs, xfs and nfs) and POSIX systems, this way we don't have to write the same code many times to make a uniform device interface.

Answer (score 0):

The questioner never specified which operating systems they were supporting (one link was to a Linux man page the other to a SCO one) so it's hard to answer this without speculation.

At the time of writing Linux doesn't supports `AIO_RAW` because glibc's `struct aiocb` doesn't have an `aio_flags` member (https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Asynchronous-I_002fO.html ) and the in kernel AIO (which is NOT POSIX) doesn't support a `AIO_RAW` value. So:

> are there any differences between using O_DIRECT and AIO_RAW? Or should I/can I use both?

Yes because not all operating systems with POSIX AIO support (such as Linux) allow you to set `AIO_RAW` and given that there will definitely be situations where you can't use both. Further, on some operating systems such as Linux `O_DIRECT` can work for files inside filesystems AND on devices whereas `AIO_RAW` is intended only for a "raw device". Judging from the dt source code it looks like `AIO_RAW` was only supported on HP-UX and SCO Unix so it's probably of limited use with other OSes.