# Does twisted epollreactor use non-blocking dns lookup?

Tags: python, dns, twisted

It seems obvious that it would use the twisted names api and not any blocking way to resolve host names.
However digging in the source code, I have been unable to find the place where the name resolution occurs. Could someone point me to the relevant source code where the host resolution occurs ( when trying to do a `connectTCP`, for example).
I really need to be sure that `connectTCP` wont use blocking DNS resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *seems* obvious, doesn't it?

Unfortunately:

1. Name resolution is not always configured in the obvious way. You think you just have to read `/etc/resolv.conf`?  Even in the specific case of Linux and DNS, you might have to look in an arbitrary number of files looking for name servers.
2. Name resolution is much more complex than just DNS.  You have to do mDNS resolution, possibly look up some LDAP computer records, and then you have to honor local configuration dictating the ordering between these such as `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.
3. Name resolution is not exposed via a standard or useful non-blocking API.  Even the glibc-specific [`getaddrinfo_a`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo_a) exposes its non-blockingness via SIGIO, not just a file descriptor you can watch.  Which means that, [like POSIX AIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87892/what-is-the-status-of-posix-asynchronous-i-o-aio), it's probably just a kernel thread behind your back anyway.

For these reasons, among others, Twisted defaults to using a resolver that just calls `gethostbyname` in a thread.

However, if you know that *for your application* it is appropriate to have DNS-only hostname resolution, and you'd like to use `twisted.names` rather than your platform resolver - in other words, if scale matters more to you than esoteric name-resolution use-cases - that is supported.  You can [install](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorPluggableResolver.html#installResolver) a [resolver](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IResolverSimple.html) from [`twisted.names.client`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.names.client.Resolver.html) onto the reactor, [appropriately configured for your application](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.names.client.Resolver.html#__init__) and all future built-in name resolutions will be made with that resolver.

Comment: A great answer, thanks! I struggled for a while to understand why are there a ThreadedResolver and twisted.names, and how are they related. It'd be nice to have this comment to twisted docs :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not massively familiar with `twisted`, I only recently started used it. It looks like it doesn't block though, but only on platforms that support threading.

In `twisted.internet.base` in `ReactorBase` it looks like it does the resolving through it's `resolve` method which returns a deferred from `self.resolver.getHostByName`.

`self.resolver` is an instance of `BlockingResolver` by default which does block, but it looks like that if the platform supports threading the resolver instance is replaced by `ThreadedResolver` in the `ReactorBase._initThreads` method.