# better way to write to file (blocking IO operation) in Twisted

Tags: python, twisted

I heard that we should avoid IO blocking operation in Twisted framework,

But what about I have to export received data to external txt file

Now I write my code in this way,

Is there any better solution ? Thanks

```
class BeginningPrinter(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, finished):
        self.finished = finished
        self.counter = 0

    def dataReceived(self, bytes):        
            self.counter += 1
            f = open('export.txt', 'a')
            f.write(bytes)
```

Answer (score 8):

Blocking file I/O should be avoided in Twisted for much the same reason any blocking operations should be avoided.  Any single thread can only do one thing at a time.  If that thread is the reactor thread and the thing you have it doing is blocking on an operation to complete then no other work you've assigned to the reactor is going to make progress until that operation finishes.  This leads to poor use of resources and unresponsive applications.

This is particularly problematic when your program blocks on network I/O because networks are slow.  Even worse than being slow, often the program on the other end of the network can't be relied on to be particularly cooperative.  It may intentionally go slowly, particularly if its operator learns this will have a negative impact on your software.

Disk I/O is a slightly different case from this.  Compared to networks, disks are often fast (your local network might be faster than your disk but your disk is probably faster than random connections across the public internet).  Disks are usually also not malicious (they don't try to service your requests as slowly as possible).  Because of this, many programs written using Twisted consider filesystem operations to be "fast enough" and disregard the fact that technically they're done using blocking I/O.

There are exceptional cases where you might want to go another route.  For one application I have worked on, the expected case was for the disk bandwidth to be almost completely used almost all of the time by other software running on the same machine.  This often resulted in simple filesystem operations in the Twisted-using process taking hundreds or thousands of milliseconds which resulted in an unacceptable performance degradation.  In this case we opted to move filesystem operations to a second process and drive them with a simple protocol running over a UNIX socket.

Since the tools for [asynchronous filesystem operations are quite primitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87892/what-is-the-status-of-posix-asynchronous-i-o-aio), going this route incurs a non-trivial additional development cost.  You should consider whether your application is actually going to suffer from the 1ms or 2ms wait times (or lower, given the rise of SSDs) it will incur for doing blocking disk I/O under most normal circumstances or whether your software might need to function well under circumstances of extraordinary disk load before deciding which route to take.