# Twisted read file asynchronously

Tags: python, asynchronous, twisted

I want to read a big file asynchronously, 20 lines at time, how we can do this using twisted framework ?

a snippet of my code, but is blocking:

```
with open(file_path) as f:
    if (importState.status == ImportStateFile.STATUS_AWAY):
        f.seek(importState.fileIndex, 0)

    while True:
        importState.fileIndex = importState.fileIndex + len(''.join(emails))
        d1 = get_emails(f)
        d1.addCallback(process_emails).addCallback(insert_emails_status)
        d1.addErrback(finalize_import)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Twisted Producer and Consumer System, follow this link to know more: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/producers.html

My producer:

```
@implementer(IBodyProducer)
class ListEmailProducer(FileBodyProducer):

    def _writeloop(self, consumer):
        """
        Return an iterator which reads one chunk of bytes from the input file
        and writes them to the consumer for each time it is iterated.
        """
        while True:
            emails = list(islice(self._inputFile, self._readSize))
            if len(emails) == 0:
                self._inputFile.close()
                consumer.finish()
                break

            consumer.write(emails)
            yield None
```

My Consumer:

```
class ListEmailConsumer():
    producer = None
    finished = False
    unregistered = True
    importState = None

    def registerImportState(self, importState):
        self.importState = importState

    def registerProducer(self, producer):
        self.producer = producer

    def unregisterProducer(self):
        self.unregistered = True

    def finish(self):
        finalize_import(self.importState)
        reactor.callFromThread(reactor.stop)

    def write(self, emails):
        self.producer.pauseProducing()
        d = process_emails(emails, self.importState)
        d.addCallback(insert_emails_status, self.importState)
        d.addCallback(lambda ignored: self.producer.resumeProducing())
```

Execution:

```
fileObj = open(file_path)

listEmailProducer = ListEmailProducer(fileObj, readSize=20)
listEmailConsumer = ListEmailConsumer()
listEmailConsumer.registerProducer(listEmailProducer)
listEmailConsumer.registerImportState(importState)
listEmailProducer.startProducing(listEmailConsumer)
```

Comment: Bear in mind that the reads in this code are still synchronous and blocking.  They're just kept small.  Quite often this is good enough because disks are usually fast and only reading a little bit at a time protects you from the problems of reading an entire, enormous file all at once.  But remember that *sometimes* disks are slow (in fact, if the disk is a contended resource, the read could take an arbitrarily long time - just like a network operation).

Comment: @jean-paul-calderone you are right, this code is blocking, I think is good to use a deferred queue, what do you think ?

Comment: To be completely non-blocking, you need a non-blocking file I/O API (you need to replace `fileObj.read` (or, to match up with your example more exactly, `next(iter(fileObj))`) with something that doesn't block.  Python doesn't have such an API.  You can use threads or you can bind a platform-specific API for doing this (and hope it works - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87892/what-is-the-status-of-posix-asynchronous-i-o-aio)

Comment: Since disk is blocking,there is another part in my code that's block, when I read 20 emails from the the file, I execute 20 deferred threads to check each email and wait for result then insert this 20 emails to DB, how to enhance this ? instead to wait we can have a buffer if this buffer raise it's limit suppose 20 then insert to DB.

Comment: Sorry, you lost me.  There's no threads in your question **or** your answer.  If you want to ask a new question, maybe ask a new question.

Comment: heheh :p, Yeah I lost you sorry :D