# How to read from (hdf5) file in async contexts?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, asgi, starlette

Lately I've been playing around a little with the python 3 async features. Overal I'm quit happy with the 3.6 syntax and of course the performance boost you gain. One of the exciting projects evolving around the `ASGI` standard in my opinion is [starlette](https://github.com/encode/starlette). I've got a sample app running where I'm reading data from a `hdf5` file. `h5py` does not support asynchronous I/O yet. Which leaves me with the question: does what I'm doing here make any sense at all? To my understanding this code runs synchronously after all. What is the recommended way to do I/O in async contexts?

```
async def _flow(indexes):
    print('received flow indexes %s ' %indexes)
    # uses h5py under the hood
    gr = GridH5ResultAdmin(gridadmin_f, results_f)
    t = gr.nodes.timeseries(indexes=indexes)
    data = t.only('s1').data
    # data is a numpy array
    return data['s1'].tolist()

@app.route('/flow_velocity')
async def flow_results(request):

    indexes_list = [[2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9], [10,11,12,13]]

    tasks = []
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    t0 = datetime.datetime.now()
    for indexes in indexes_list:
        print('Start getting indexes %s' % indexes)
        # Launch a coroutine for each data fetch
        task = loop.create_task(_flow(indexes))
        tasks.append(task)

    # Wait on, and then gather, all data
    flow_data = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    dt = (datetime.datetime.now() - t0).total_seconds()
    print('elapsed time: {} [s]'.format(dt))

    return JSONResponse({'flow_velocity': flow_data})
```

Logging:

```
INFO: Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Start getting indexes "[2, 3, 4, 5]"
Start getting indexes "[6, 7, 8, 9]"
Start getting indexes "[10, 11, 12, 13]"
received flow indexes [2, 3, 4, 5] 
received flow indexes [6, 7, 8, 9] 
received flow indexes [10, 11, 12, 13]
elapsed time: 1.49779 [s]
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately with `h5py` module you can't use the `asyncio`, what you do here is majorly sequential, because if the I/O part can't be done asynchronously, then rest of the part of your async code doesn't have much meaning left

https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/837

**Summary from that thread**

> So there are two separate issues with adding asyncio support:
>
> 1. asyncio explicitly does not support filesystem I/O at this time, see e.g. https://github.com/python/asyncio/wiki/ThirdParty#filesystem, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-tulip/MvpkQeetWZA, [What is the status of POSIX asynchronous I/O (AIO)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87892/what-is-the-status-of-posix-asynchronous-i-o-aio), and https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles which is the closest to want you'd want.
> 2. All I/O is done through HDF5 (the library), so whatever async support you'd want to add would need support in HDF5 (the library)
>
> This basically means that h5py is unlikely to ever support asyncio.
>
> You could try running things in a thread, no guarantees it will work well though, as I mentioned, HDF5 controls the I/O, and you will want to make sure you don't run into any of its locking controls. You probably will want to understand which file mode mentioned at http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/file.html#file-drivers will work best for you. Maybe you could consider other alternatives such as multiprocessing or concurrent.futures?

Comment: You can pass h5py a python file-like object to h5py and then implement asyncio at the level of the file-like object (implement read, write, truncate, etc), I've got an example of that working (with much effort), but I think I may be running into the h5 locking mechanisms you mention here because things appear to run nearly sequential, though the same code with raw `.read()` calls on the file-like object runs extremely quickly - 1.5 GB/sec random-seek ingest using asyncio (w/ 20 event loop instances) from a local cluster S3 interface.

Comment: There has been some progress in HDF5 space regarding asynchronous I/O: https://hdf5-vol-async.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ , but no python binding I'm aware of.